# How do I connect the endpoint & startpoint of geom_line in a polar plot (coord_polar)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geometry, line-plot

I'm a bit stuck with getting the endpoint of a line in a polar plot to connect with the startpoint.

My data:

```
df <- structure(list(ri = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360),
                 n = c(329L, 315L, 399L, 700L, 919L, 757L, 656L, 918L, 1117L, 976L, 878L, 803L, 811L, 1072L, 1455L, 1642L, 1891L, 1688L, 1553L, 1841L, 2061L, 2321L, 2498L, 2080L, 1595L, 1080L, 1002L, 953L, 729L, 604L, 538L, 489L, 535L, 455L, 328L, 351L, 329L),
                 d = c(0.008581340149717, 0.00821617673909074, 0.0104071572028483, 0.0182581705313128, 0.0239703695975378, 0.0197449072745768, 0.017110514097916, 0.0239442864967787, 0.0291348235478234, 0.0254571063408018, 0.022900962466418, 0.0209447299094916, 0.0211533947155638, 0.0279610840136675, 0.0379509116043715, 0.0428284514463079, 0.0493231435353035, 0.0440282740812228, 0.0405070554787553, 0.0480189884973526, 0.0537572706643366, 0.0605388768616813, 0.0651555856960275, 0.0542528495787579, 0.0416025457106341, 0.0281697488197397, 0.0261352669605363, 0.0248571950233444, 0.0190145804533243, 0.015754192858447, 0.0140327082083518, 0.0127546362711599, 0.0139544589060748, 0.0118678108453533, 0.00855525704895798, 0.0091551683664154, 0.008581340149717)),
            .Names = c("ri", "n", "d"), row.names = c(NA, 37L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My first attempt at making a polar-plot with this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ri, y=d)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,10)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

[image]

This produces more or less what I want. However, I like to have an y-axis that starts at `0`. 
Therefore, I used the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ri, y=d)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.07), breaks=seq(0,0.06,0.01)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

Unfortunately, now the line ends at `350` and does not connect with `0/360`:
[image]

Next I tried:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ri, y=d)) +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA, color="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,360,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.07), breaks=seq(0,0.06,0.01)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

This code does connect the endpoint with the startpoint, but also creates a circle:
[image]

I also tried `geom_path`, but that gave the same result as `geom_polygon`. Analysing the problem further, I tried to make a normal plot with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ri, y=d)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq(0,360,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.07), breaks=seq(0,0.06,0.01)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

which gives:
[image]

As you can see, there is a line between `350` and `360`. Doing the same with `geom_plygon`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ri, y=d)) +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA, color="black") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq(0,360,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.07), breaks=seq(0,0.06,0.01)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

which results in:
[image]

Again, using `geom_path` instead of `geom_polygon` gives the same result. So, the problem seems to result from setting the limits for the y-axis in combination with `coord_polar`.

**My questions:**

1. How do I connect the endpoint and the startingpoint in a polar-plot with an y-axis starting at `0` when using `geom_line` in combination with `coord_polar`?
2. Or without getting a circle in the middel when using `geom_polygon`/`geom_path` in combination with `coord_polar`?

Note:
The original dataset did not have a row for `ri=0`. I added this row myself. It is a duplication of the `ri=360` row.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057038/in-ggplot2-with-polar-coordinates-connect-points-with-geom-path-across-0-2pi-wi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trail and error, I got what I wanted with the following steps:

1. Removing the row for `ri=360` (which is a duplicate of `ri=0`) with `df <- df[df$ri!=360,]`
2. Transforming `ri` to a factor & adding `group=1` to the `aes`.
3. Adding `start=-pi*1/36` to `coord_polar` in order to get the `0` at the top of the polar plot

This results in the following `ggplot` code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(ri), y=d, group=1)) +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA, color="black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.07), breaks=seq(0,0.06,0.01)) +
  coord_polar(start=-pi*1/36) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: @Gregor There was a mistake in the `dput` in the question, which I corrected. I also explained my solution better in my answer. I hope everithing is clear now. If it's still not working for you, could you then post your code in a comment?

Comment: This does not work for me, because my data are not regularly spaced, so I can't convert the x to a factor. I have data height data as a function of time and longitude and over time the prime meridian is crossed multiple times and I'd like to be able to connect the dots as they pass.

Comment: Now addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057038/in-ggplot2-with-polar-coordinates-connect-points-with-geom-path-across-0-2pi-wi

Answer (score 0):

It's a side effect of how you have set the limits of the y scale. Using:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=ri, y=d)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq(0,360,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,0.06,0.01)) +
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

[image]

This is odd because values > 0 shouldn't be truncated by `ylim(0, 0.07)`, but there it is...

Comment: Thanx for answering. Unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for. I didn't include this in my question, but this was actually my first attempt. However, I like to have an y-axis which starts at `0`. I will update my question to illustrate that.

Comment: See my own answer for a solution to this problem.